# Bash script doesn't get all parameters that i've given

Tags: bash

I've a simple bash script to run the parameter as a command on the server, the necessity for this i am creating the required command as a string on the other server and trying to execute it remotely.

```
PROFILE=/coremedia/home/picroot/.profile
source $PROFILE
"$1"
```

the parameter i am sending to script :

`/coremedia/pic-cms-tools/bin/cm publish -u admin -p admin -t "/Config/Static Texts/PDF Texts/pdf.eudatasheet.ocEnergyConsConvAlone" "/Config/Static Texts/PDF Texts/pdf.eudatasheet.ocEnergyConsForcedAlone"`

But it couldn't find the necessary command it is stopped when we reached :

```
/coremedia/pic-cms-tools/bin/cm
```

I've tried many configurations on my side to handle the string but i've still couldn't reach a solution, obviously i am missing a small critical thing...

Any help would be appreciated, many thanks in advance!

Comment: Don't use eval unless you are certain of the content in the string, i.e it is a fixed value.

Comment: I would rephrase: Use eval if only you are certain of the string contents (it seem to be the case in the OP's example).

Comment: you can do this: `cmd=$1; shift; $cmd "$@"`. this will run your params with the first param as command entry

Comment: Are you calling this script with multiple arguments quoted correctly? If you are then you don't need `eval` at all and can just use `"$@"` as the command (possibly `exec "$@"` to replace the current shell).

Comment: Many thanks for your answers, I missed this small detail somehow...

Comment: EDIT = The parameter case is solved, now it is changing...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace `eval $1` with `eval "$@"` to evaluate all the parameters, not just the first one.

Comment: Hello Rosca, could you please check my edit if it can be done for you ?

Comment: Hello! Try to escape the single quotes using backslashes! `/coremedia/pic-cms-tools/bin/cm publish -u admin -p admin -t \'/Config/Static Texts/PDF Texts/pdf.eudatasheet.ocEnergyConsConvAlone\' \'/Config/Static Texts/PDF Texts/pdf.eudatasheet.ocEnergyConsForcedAlone\'`

Comment: You got me wrong i think, single quotes are necessary on the string to run the coommand succesfully, but from remote i am sending same thing it removes the quotes on the command..

Comment: @Hayra: Honestly and seriously, running your script remotely is simply another issue and you should open another question! I made some experiments and you are right, the quotes are lost. The solution isn't trivial as I thought initially!